# PySpark unable to drop column after join using table_name.colname notation, is there a better way?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a master table, on which I am joining multiple smaller tables.
I have to drop the column `cat` present in all the smaller tables, but both the method below are not working.

```
a = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2],'cat':['a','b']}))
b = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'id':[3,4],'cat':[None,'b']}))
c = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,4],'cat':['c','d']}))

p = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5]}))

(
    p
    .join(a,'id')
    .join(b,'id')
    .join(c,'id')
    .withColumn('category',F.expr('coalesce(a.cat,b.cat,c.cat)'))
    .drop('a.cat','b.cat','c.cat')
).columns
# output: ['id', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'category']
(
    p
    .join(a.alias('a'),'id')
    .join(b.alias('b'),'id')
    .withColumn('category',F.expr('coalesce(a.cat,b.cat,c.cat)'))
    .drop('a.cat','b.cat')
).columns
# output: ['id', 'cat', 'cat', 'category]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the needed columns:

```
(
    p
    .join(a,'id')
    .join(b,'id')
    .join(c,'id')
    .select(
        'id',
        *[p[i] for i in p.columns if i != 'id'],
        *[a[i] for i in a.columns if i != 'id' and i != 'cat'],
        *[b[i] for i in b.columns if i != 'id' and i != 'cat'],
        *[c[i] for i in c.columns if i != 'id' and i != 'cat']
    )
).columns
```

Comment: Actually there is also a withColumn() after the joins, which uses a case when on all the `cat` columns coming in via smaller tables, hence can't do this.

Comment: Haha, this is better. This will work for sure. Apologies for not accepting this, as I feel this should be doable using just the `drop` method, as I want to keep my code concise (the audience is used to SQL)

Comment: In SQL you can't do `drop`, but you select the needed columns (which is what I did). `drop` is a spark thing and doesn't work well with columns having the same name

Comment: or you could consider renaming the cat columns to cat_a, cat_b, etc. before joining, then you can use `drop`

Comment: I agree with the rename the column beforehand advice. But any idea why could drop not be working? I see drop can take multiple strings as input, it doesnt expect list, and it is able to drop other columns also. You think issue is with appending alias_name?

Comment: there is no such column `a.cat`. The column is called `cat`, not `a.cat`. You cannot reference table aliases in `drop`.